# Cannot trigger List Workflow with an item created by workflow (SP 2013 Online)

Tags: 2013, workflow

I cannot seem to trigger a list workflow using items created by another workflow.

The items are created as me, not System Account. When I create an item manually through the browser it works fine. It is just items created or changed via workflow that do not trigger the list workflow. Does anyone have a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default SharePoint behavior (works the same way in 2010 too).  However, in 2013, SPD workflows have a Start Workflow action available.  This means you can trigger the workflow on the item in the workflow that created the item.  What I would suggest doing is in the second workflow, have it set a field on the item indicating that it is complete.  This way, at the beginning of the second workflow, you can first check to see if it has already run before trying to run again.

The only other solution involves a programmatic approach, which won't help you with SharePoint Online.

Comment: John, I am having the same issue. I don't think it works the same way as SP 2010. In the previous version, when a workflow changed a field, this triggered workflows on the modified item. As for the Start Workflow action, unfortunately it can only start SP 2010 workflows.

Comment: I think "Start Workflow" action can only start a 2010 WF.

Answer (score 1):

As John Chapman said, that is the default behavior of SharePoint. But, instead of adding another step to the first workflow, saying it to run a 2010 WF on another item and list, you can make the second workflow as a 2010 workflow, and not 2013, in SPD.

So the first workflow (1WF) - that can be of 2010 or 2013 - just creates an item in another list. This latter list has a 2010 WF (2WF) associated with it.

When 1WF creates an item, 2WF starts accordingly, only if it's created as a 2010 WF.

For me this worked.

Cheers